# Add button on product page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-button

I want to add a button only on those products which are having product size.Button displaying over Color attribute.[image]

My XML file is catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Button" name="myButton" template="VENDOR_MODULE::button.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>    
</body>
</page>
```

Right now it is displaying on all products.
**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: if you are creating color/size with configurable product, you can use `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` instead of `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

Comment: Thanks alot its working.

Comment: Can you tell me how to move this button between Color and Size?

Comment: it can be shown above to colour Or below to size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating `color/size` with configurable product, you can use `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` instead of `catalog_product_view.xml`

It will only applicable to `configurable product`

Comment: Yes, agreed....